# Allignment of boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

Go to this link to get the code

```
http://jsfiddle.net/o3rh4oeb/
```

Go to this link for actual design I want.

```
http://www.bbc.com/news/
```

See here my problem is the white spaces,between the boxes.How to get rid of it,I tried both margin and padding 0px but never worked for top one not the below one :(
help me please...

Comment: have you tried anything ? if so please show.have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please.

Comment: i have a slow internet connection so how do i can see your links?

Comment: Hey I got one problem resolved but.Check here:http://jsfiddle.net/o3rh4oeb/ But a small line is left out,I tried margin and padding :0px for both never worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ul` in the `#topicmenu` section has a `margin-top` applied by the browser. You just need to remove it:

```
#topicmenu ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```